# How can I edit an .ini file with a korn shell script?

Tags: ksh, ini

I have a .ini file that looks like this

```
[test]
  foo=bar
```

My file is called test.ini

I want to write a korn shell that will modify my test.ini file for the following

```
    [test]
      foo=barzar
```

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
sed -i.bak '/^\[test]/,/^\[/{s/^foo[[:space:]]*=.*/foo = foobarbaz/}' test.ini
```

Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Does your `sed` support `-z` ? If not, look at `awk` or `ed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to change `foo=something` in a `[test]` block:

`sed -i.bak '/^\[test\]/,/^\s*foo\s*=/ s/^\s*foo\s*=.*/  foo = barzar/' test.ini`

The first part makes up an address of lines between `[test]` and a line containing `foo =` with optional spaces before foo and after foo. The substitution will only happen here.
First part: `/^\[test\]/,/^\s*foo\s*=/`

The second part is the substitution with blanks insertion before foo, after foo, and after =:
Second part: `s/^\s*foo\s*=.*/  foo = barzar/`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(foo=bar)/$1zar/g' test.ini
```